# Value of variable is not stored correctly while transfering the value from HTML form to PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Thanks Ben, but now the other issue that I am facing is that result is not being displayed first time when I add the pagination to the code. See the second half of the code below. Please help

```
if(isset($_GET['k'])){ $k1 = $_GET['k']; } else { $k1 = ''; }
echo $k1;
    $term = explode(" ", $k1);

$query = "SELECT * FROM database ";

foreach ($term as $each) 
{
    echo $each;
$i++;
    if($i==1)
    {
        $query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

else {
    $query .= "OR WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

}

$per_pages=3;
$page_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('title') FROM kcpdatabase");
    $pages = ceil(mysql_result($page_query, 0)/$per_pages)  or die

       ($page_query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());    
       $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) 
       ($_GET['page']) : 1;                             
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_pages;  
$query .= "LIMIT $start, $per_pages";


$ourquery1 = mysql_query ($query);
if(!$ourquery1)
echo "No query found";
$row1 = mysql_num_rows ($ourquery1);

if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){ 

    for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++)
    {

        echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
    }

if ($row1 > 0)
{

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ourquery1))
    {
           echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        $title = $result['title'];
        $link = $result['link'];
        $region = $result['region'];
        $sector = $result['sector'];
        $theme = $result['theme'];      
        echo "<td> <a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";
        echo "<h4>Sector: $sector <br>Theme: $theme <br> Region: $region  
                          </td>  </tr>";
    }
}   

}
echo "</tbody>";
```

Below is a portion of my code where I am trying to search a word/ phrase entered in the text box. When I catch the value from the form in a php file using "$k1 = isset($_GET['k']);" the value which get's stored in variable "$each" is "1" and NOT the word or phrase entered by the user. This messess up the query which is performing the search function. Please help me to locate the error.

Please note that 'k' is the name of text box as defined in the form code below.

```
    <form name="keywordquery" method="get" action="page2.php">
<fieldset class="fieldsetclass"><legend class="legendclass">Search by Keywords</legend>
      <div id="searchbox">
<input type="text" name="k" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['k'])){echo htmlentities($_GET
       ['k']);} ?>" style="border: 1px, thin; width:92%; "/> 
<input type="image" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 2px;" src="search.png"
      value="submit" />
</div>
</fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">

    <tbody>    
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('', '', '');
if(!$connection)
echo "No database connected";
$dbase = mysql_select_db("", $connection);
if(!$dbase)
echo "No datatable connected";



$k1 = isset($_GET['k']);
echo $k1;
$term = explode(" ", $k1);

$query = "SELECT * FROM datatable ";

foreach ($term as $each) 
{
    echo $each;
$i++;
    if($i==1)
    {
        $query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

else {
    $query .= "OR WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

}
```

Comment: $k1 = isset($_GET['k']); does not get the value, only tells whether or not it IS SET

Comment: isset results in a boolean. so $k1 is 0 or 1 not what is stored in $_GET['k']

Comment: [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) just determines whether or not the variable is set.  Please read php.net for how the function works ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$k1 = isset($_GET['k']);
```

It's setting `$k1` as 1 as it's ckecking to see if it's been set - in this case it has been and `isset()` is returning true, or 1.

what you want is:

```
if(isset($_GET['k'])){ $k1 = $_GET['k']; } else { $k1 = ''; }
```

or similar.

Comment: Also possible, but teaching the ternary operator might lead to more confusion

Comment: you've got your : and ? backwords @Jon

Comment: Bah!  Fixed.  Thank you @ElefantPhace, fixed it before I saw the comment >< Posted too quick.  And very `True` Ben. =]

Answer (score 0):

Thats because isset() is a bool function, check following link http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

just do this

```
if(isset($_GET['k']))
    $k1 = $_GET['k'];
```